Can not boot Ubuntu because file system of Linux partition is not Recognized by GRUB in Dual Boot
TLDR: In a dual boot with one Windows and one Ubuntu partition, GRUB started in terminal-mode, and I couldn't boot Ubuntu (but I could boot Windows). My Ubuntu partition was still there, but the filesystem wasn't recognized (neither in GRUB, nor in testdisk), so I couldn't access my data. Running fsck fixed the problem.
Problem Description
I have a dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo Ideapad Pro 5 using GRUB (v2.06).
When I tried to boot today, instead of showing the normal GRUB menu to choose between Windows and Ubuntu, GRUB directly starts in terminal-mode, and I can not boot into my Ubuntu (I have not tried to boot into Windows, since I want to make sure not to overwrite anything). I found different answers regarding similar problems online and tried them out, but couldn't find a solution to my problem yet.

Grub2 starts in commanline after restart and can't find /boot or /grub: Similar to this post, I can not find a grub/ or boot/ directory in any partition within the GRUB terminal, which was the baseline for most suggestions I read. Similar to the post, my (hd0,gpt1)/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg looks like this:

Nevertheless I assume that my ubuntu-partition is not deleted (in contrast to the problem in the post):  I assume that (hd0,gpt5) is the partition assigned to Ubuntu. But it can somehow not be recognized by GRUB ("No known filesystem detected"). I booted Ubuntu live via USB-stick and installed TestDisk. However when trying to view files within the Linux partition it states "Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged":

https://superuser.com/questions/1332137/grub-rescue-says-all-partitions-have-filesystem-is-unknown: As recommended in this post I also installed BootRepair with the resulting error "The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.", see https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Pz9PTY4XS8/ for my full BootRepair-log. Mounting the Ubuntu partition did also not work: "NTFS signature is missing".

I am really unsure what to do next since I do not find any post with this specific problem and I don't want to break more than is already damaged. Running fsck was recommended in a few posts, but also brings a lot of risks as I read in other posts (similar to just booting into Windows), so I did not want to just try it out without knowing if it could be helpful in my case. Of course it would be great if it was possible to somehow restore the partitions, but at the moment my main concern is to find any way to somehow backup and save my data from the Ubuntu partition (there are no important files on Windows).
I hope I included all necessary information and would be very thankful for any advice and help. Of course I will gladly provide any further information when necessary.
UPDATE 1: I can boot into Windows, the latest updates are installed and Fast Startup is disabled. This did not fix the issue.
UPDATE 2: I created an image of the disk and am now working on the image to prevent any risks (therefore, the corrupted drive is now called /dev/sdf, and the corrupted partition with my Ubuntu is in /dev/sdf).
I ran fsck on the Linux partition, and the output is:

fsck from util-linux 2.37.2 e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021) ext2fs_open2:
Bad magic number in super-block fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying
backup blocks... fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while
trying to open /dev/sdf5

As described in https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/, I used sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdf5 to list where the backup superblocks are stored. I tried every possible block number in the list by running sudo e2fsck -b <block_number> /dev/sdf5; however, this always gives the result: "e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdf5". Hence, I could not fix the corrupted partition using fsck/e2fsck.
Did I do anything wrong in the usage of fsck/e2fsck? Do you have any suggestions what I could try next?

I suggest you start by booting Windows directly via UEFI seetings - Boot menu. If successful then make sure to install all pending updates, rebboting as much times as it needs, and lastly disable Fast Startup, a must when dual booting. After all this change the boot order back to Ubuntu and give it a try. If Windows can't boot directly then you have a problem with that drive.

Thanks for your suggestion, I have also thought about that. In case I have a problem with the drive, do you know whether there is any risk in booting into Windows? Is it possible that Windows overwrites any disk space that would else be recoverable with tools like TestDisk/photorec?

It won't overwrite (or even try to) anything in partitions it doesn't "understand".

Booting into Windows worked, updates are installed and fast Startup is disabled. Unfortunately the problem remains exactly the same.

Now you narrowed down the problem to something in the Linux system partition (where the GRUB 2nd stage runs from). You may need to error correct the Linux partitions with tools from a live session.

You may need fsck on your Linux partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run  If not run Summary Report from Boot-Repair to see details. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Thank you! Do you need more than the boot repair pastebin link included in the post (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Pz9PTY4XS8/)? Regarding fsck: Can I use fsck without any writing on the disk in case I need to use a data recovery tool? In other words, can I do more harm by running fsck by overwriting disk space that would else be recoverable?

I just updated the post after running fsck on an image. Do you have any further suggestions on what I could do to save my disk?

e2fsck is specific to filesystems of types ext2/ext3/ext4. For other filesystem types, a different tool is needed. The generic fsck will default to e2fsck if no filesystem type information is available and you didn't use the -t option to specify the actual filesystem type. Because the partition table gives no clues of the exact filesystem type and GRUB fails to identify it, you should first identify it. Try file -s /dev/sdf5 and see if it can identify the filesystem type.

The filesystem type can not be recognized (file -s just returns data). However, since I'm sure that this is my Ubuntu partition, shouldn't the filesystem be ext4?

Ok, the problem is solved. Apparently, something went wrong when I ran fsck on the disk image or the partition in the disk image, so it failed to fix the partition. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions, in the end it was really just an fsck on the actual partition needed :)

What fixed it in the end: I used testdisk to create an image only of the Ubuntu partition. Then I ran fsck on this image (even though I'm not 100% sure that this did anything...). Afterward, the partition was fixed, and I had access to my data in testdisk. Therefore, I ran fsck on my actual partition in a live session afterward (command sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p5), said yes to every suggested fix, and now everything is back to normal. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions, in the end it was really just an fsck needed :)
